# Replacing values in pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

I am looking for a pythonic way of replacing values based on whether values are big of small. Say I have a data frame:

```
ds = pandas.DataFrame({'x' : [4,3,2,1,5], 'y' : [4,5,6,7,8]})
```

I'd like to replace values on x which are lower than 2 by 2 and values higher than 4 by 4. And similarly with y values, replacing values lower than 5 by 5 and values higher than 7 by 7 so as to get this data frame:

```
ds = pandas.DataFrame({'x' : [4,3,2,2,4], 'y' : [5,5,6,7,7]})
```

I did it by iterating on the rows but is really ugly, any more pandas-pythonic way (Basically I want to eliminate extreme values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `clip`

```
ds.x.clip(2,4)
Out[42]: 
0    4
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    4
Name: x, dtype: int64
#ds.x=ds.x.clip(2,4)
#ds.y=ds.y.clip(5,7)
```

Comment: Amazing! this is exactly what I was looking for. A dozen ugly lines replaced by one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this as follows:

```
>>> ds[ds.x.le(2) ] =2
>>> ds[ds.x.ge(4) ] =4
>>> ds
   x  y
0  4  4
1  3  5
2  2  6
3  2  2
4  4  4
```

Comment: @JuanChô, Glad it helps :-)